# Need to CTRL-C "less" in order to see file?

Tags: linux, less, file-corruption

I have never seen this behavior before using "less" and am wondering if it speaks to a corrupted file?
Typically when I use `less <filename>` the file is immediately displayed.  In the case of a few files I must hit CTRL-C before any action will take effect.  In other words, the command prompt does not return until CTRL-C. 
I have tried `ls -b` to display any garbage in the filename and also tried `less -ru` to see if there were corrupted characters in the file.  Neither have revealed anything unusual.

Comment: Sometimes less takes too long to calculate the line numbers and you can stop that by pressing `ctrl-c`. But that only happens with large files.

Comment: Exactly.  That's the only time I've seen that behavior which is strange.  These files are under 1K in size.

Comment: Of all things - crazy - there was a 0 length file named 'grep' in the same directory.  Removing it allowed 'less' to function as normal.  I only found it because I happened to try to do a grep command from the directory.  Better question is why less was affected.  The grep command I understand - but less??

Comment: @McArthey This is (a mild instance of) the reason that it's not recommended to have `.` on your `PATH`: you can end up accidentally running any old garbage instead of the command you meant to run. That can be very dangerous, especially if you're using an account with administrator privileges.

Comment: Completely agree but also seems like our upgrade of Linux was also partly to blame.